# PHP Webdriver: Does WebDriverWait behaves differently with Firefox?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I recently switched from Chrome to Firefox standalone server and now the following 2 lines of code are returning an error

```
$wait = new WebDriverWait($driver, 30);
$wait->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::visibilityOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::xpath('//select/option[@value="50"]')));
```

the error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeoutException in WebDriverWait.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 : Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverWait->until(Object(WebDriverExpectedCondition))
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the switching to Firefox standalone server. Is there something I need to modify in terms of how **WebDriverExpectedCondition** is used?

I'm using the docker image: `selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-20210311`

**Is it possible that xpath has to be in a different format for FireFox?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone runs into this, the issue is not with the `WebDriverWait`, but with the way Xpath needs to be formatted

Chrome and FF differ in how you have to write it, so if you change browsers you may have to update Xpaths as well